# Facebook Groups URL link from Android Browser

Tags: html, facebook

there are url link for call Facebook Groups Android Apps from Android Browser?

example, Facebook Apps can use

> fb://detail

what is facebook Groups (com.facebook.groups) ?

and how i call the group by id? 
in facebook i can use

> fb://group/fbGroupID

what is in facebook Groups apps?

Comment: this is not same like that @CBroe , that existing question is talk about facebook application, i ask about facebook Groups (com.facebook.groups), i was repeat ask "hat is facebook Groups (com.facebook.groups) ?" and "what is in facebook Groups apps?"

Comment: OK, I reopened the question.